# How value will be choose in xpath

Tags: xpath

```
<DocumentList>
  <DocumentId>node1175251</DocumentId>
  <DocumentId>node1175254</DocumentId>
  <DocumentId>node1175385</DocumentId>
</DocumentList>
```

I have this `Xml`. 
I want to select the value of `DocumentId`.
I need **xpath** for select the value. Anyone Help me?

Answer (score 1):

```
/DocumentList/DocumentId

/DocumentList/DocumentId[1]  // for the first instance
/DocumentList/DocumentId[last()]  // for the last instance
```

Also, `/DocumentList/` would ensure that /DocumentId[1] is inside DocumentList tag

Answer (score 1):

> I want to select the value of DocumentId. I need xpath for select the
>   value. Anyone Help me?

**This selects all `DocumentId` *elements*:**

```
/*/DocumentId
```

**This selects the first `DocumentId` element:**

```
/*/DocumentId[1]
```

**This selects the second `DocumentId` element:**

```
/*/DocumentId[2]
```

**This selects the last `DocumentId` element:**

```
/*/DocumentId[last()]
```

All of the above XPath expression select nodes (elements).

An XPath expression doesn't select a value. It may *produce* a value. Also, what you are actually asking for is the *string value* of a particular `DocumentId` element:

**This Xpath expression produces the string value of the first `DocumentId` element:**

```
string(/*/DocumentId[1])
```

**This Xpath expression produces the string value of the second `DocumentId` element**:

```
string(/*/DocumentId[2])
```

**This Xpath expression produces the string value of the last `DocumentId` element:**

```
string(/*/DocumentId[last()])
```

Answer (score -1):

use `.eq( index )`  java script function

to get the value of xml node using index as parameter

Comment: Where does he say he wants to use javascript?